# Inserted data from mysql takes some time to appear when fetched through lambda functions

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector-python

When I insert some data into mysql db instance deployed at rds services through

```
cursor.execute(
"""Insert into employee(id,name) Values(5,"Sayed")""",)
db.commit()
```

i could fetch them immediately from mysql workbench but when i use lambda functions to fetch them.

```
cursor.execute(
"""Select name from employee where id =5 """,)
rows =cursor.fetchone()
```

it takes few minutes to appear through lambda what causes this problem

Comment: Are you calling the Lambda function via API Gateway?

Comment: Yup i call it through api @Mark B

Comment: Do you have request caching enabled in API Gateway?

Comment: I just used the default settings at api gateway

Comment: I have checked the api cache and found it disabled

Comment: How are you executing the API call? Through a web browser?

Comment: Through mobile app

Comment: Through http dart package

Answer (score 0):

It's due to `Cold Start`. When running a Lambda function, it stays active as long as you’re running it. It means that your container stays alive, and is ready for execution. AWS can drop the container after a period of inactivity, and your function becomes inactive or cold. A cold start happens when you execute an inactive Lambda function. The execution of an inactive Lamda function happens when there are no available containers, and the function needs to start up a new one. A worm start happens when there are available containers.

You can read more about it [Here](https://aithority.com/it-and-devops/cloud/5-ways-to-prevent-aws-lambda-cold-starts/).

Comment: No i do not think that was the cause of my problem , I figured that aws try to reserve resources by maintaining the connection to database by connection pooling and this article about that issue https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/